# CefSharp.Winform - duplicate input keyboard key while sending to web form input control

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

CefSharp 73.1.120-pre01 (older version also affected)
x64, Win10, WinForms

I use CefSharp.WinForm to "host" simple Angular app with few input controls. Because of need to map some keyboard keys to some another I use IKeyboardHandler (OnPreKeyEvent).

When I return "true" from OnPreKeyEvent (bool) I am able to suppress initially pressed key BUT instead of returning just one "transformed" value he returns duplicated new value to web input control.

Simple use case

1. I press "a" in input control

2.
MyKeyHandler which implement IKeyHandler (OnPreKeyEvent) method enter his codebehind

For sending new key I used KeySend(Sys.Win.Form.SendKeys):

KeySend.SendWait("{s}")

or InputSimulatorPro Nuget package:

InputSimulator sim = new InputSimulator();
sim.Keyboard.KeyDown(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.VK_S);

3.
Web Input control receive 2 values od "s" character.

I tried SendKey.Flush / Thread.Sleep combinations but nothing has impact - I always get 2 values OUT.

Sample code (End -> Tab) <- Returns 2 tabs (it shift one web control more than it should)

```
public bool OnPreKeyEvent(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, KeyType type, int windowsKeyCode, int nativeKeyCode, CefEventFlags modifiers, bool isSystemKey, ref bool isKeyboardShortcut)
    { 
     if (windowsKeyCode == 0x23) //End > Tab
        {
            SendKey.SendWait("{TAB}");

            return true;
        }
```

ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve there is insufficient detail provided for someone else to reproduce your problem. If you haven't already see what spy++ tells you about the messages being sent to the browser

Comment: @amaitland - thank you for your reply but can you please based on my code give me some more precisely WhaToDo answer - I tried hook (SetupMessageInterceptor from BrowserTabUserControl.cs) but with no luck. And I'm not enough experienced to read Spy++ messages in reasonable way. 
I just need prevent default key and send another one, but not duplicated.

Comment: Why are you canceling the tab then immediately sending one? Makes no sense.

Comment: I'm not canceling - 0x23 is "End" key code. I want. for example, press End key and get Tab instead

Comment: How does it behave if you send keys from say a button click? Make sure the browser has focus.

Comment: When I do click in web control (instead of pressing "End") there is no event triggered (browser focus is not lost). It doesn't enter OnPreKeyEvent at all. Code:
if (windowsKeyCode == 0x01) //Left Mouse key > Tab key
{                MappingFactory(nameof(KeyboardMappingMethodsList.Map_ClickToTab));
return true;            } 
Amaitland - can you please try this during weekend.. I assume that this functionality should exist in such great piece of code like cefsharp.. 
"Essential Objects" seems to have that functionality but i prefer CefSharp so please make a magic :)

Comment: Code in comments is too hard to read, please edit your question.  Keyboard handling is entirely implemented in Chromium for the WinForms version, important to remember that CefSharp is just a wrapper.

Comment: Integrating CEF into your apps existing message loop maybe required see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#multithreadedmessageloop

Comment: I should point out there is already a supported method of sending raw key data to the browser  http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IBrowserHost_SendKeyEvent.htm

Comment: Using `SendKeys.Send` I can quite happily send the browser tabs from a button click. `SendKeys.SendWait` also works though I'd advise against waiting for a response.